# How to freeze the first row and first column on a WPF grid

Tags: wpf, scrollview, grid-layout

Is there a way to freeze the first row and first column of a grid (not data grid) in WPF? My application has a grid that contain line chart controls and I would like to have the first row to hold labels that would stay still as I scroll vertically and for the first column to hold labels that stay when I scroll horizontally. 
Anyone can share an example on how to do this?